# Counterexamples to Von Neumann's theorem on closed subgroup of GL.

Tags: matrices, manifolds, lie-groups, examples-counterexamples

I am currently working on the following:

> **Theorem.** (Von Neumann) A closed subgroup of $\textrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{K})$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{K}^{n^2}$ whose tangent vector space at the identity is given by $\mathfrak{g}:=\{X\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})\textrm{ s.t. }\forall t\in\mathbb{R},\exp(tX)\in G\}.$

Its proof relies strongly on $G$ being closed, even to show that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a subvector-space of $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{K})$. Therefore, I am wondering whether or not $G$ being closed is a necessary condition for $G$ being a submanifold.

I looked for a subgroup of $\textrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ that is not a submanifold, but in vain. My idea was to encode a degenerated hyperbola as a subgroup of $\textrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. The main problem I encountered is that was only able to release it as a subgroup of $\mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{R})$, see below:
$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\y&x\end{pmatrix};(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2,x^2-y^2=0\right\}.$$

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $GL(2, \Bbb{Q})$?

Comment: And all examples are kind of similar to that one. If $G$ is a topological group, and $H\subset G$ a subgroup, then $\overline{H}$ is a closed subgroup of $G$. So in $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$, we're looking at proper dense subgroups of some sub-Lie-group.

Comment: @RobArthan I do get why $\textrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{Q})$ is a non-closed subgroup of $\textrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. However, I failed to see why it is not a submanifold, even with the enlightenments of Daniel Fischer.

Comment: $GL(2, \Bbb{Q})$ is countable, so the only manifold structure you can put on it is 0-dimensional and gives it the discrete topology.

Comment: @RobArthan That makes sense! Thank you very much!